# Setting up a server and can't find libmysqlclient under /usr

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, libmysql

I am currently setting up a PHP 5.2 server (yes I know, but it is actually needed in this case) but I keep getting an error:

> configure: error: Cannot find libmysqlclient under /usr.

The command that I am running is:

> ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql --with-libdir

I have installed libmysqlclient and when I run

> locate libmysqlclient

I get results returned, although none of them are the file libmysqlclient (the closest is libmysqlclient.a)

I would greatly appreciate any help that can be provided.

Comment: as I recall, the mysql stuff is wonky, and you have to point configure at the parent directory. e.g. if the lib's in /foo/bar/baz/libmysql.so, you have to do `--with-mysql=/foo/bar` instead.

Comment: I gave this a shot and no such luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the DIR directive

```
--with-mysql --with-libdir=/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
```

From [Cannot find libmysqlclient under /usr. while build PHP 5.2 from source on Ubuntu 12.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134220/cannot-find-libmysqlclient-under-usr-while-build-php-5-2-from-source-on-ubuntu)

Updated from your comment!

Comment: What OS are you using Ubuntu? Did you compile libmysql or install from repo?

Comment: Using Ubuntu, I installed libmysql from repo.

Comment: --with-mysql --with-libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu Updated answer try that

Comment: No luck. Does it make a difference that the server is x32?

Comment: Got it working largely because of your answer. I used ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql --with-libdir=/lib/i386-linux-gnu/

Comment: Edit your answer for the correct directory and I will accept it

Comment: @inimrepus Are you SURE you mean x32, not i386?

Comment: @duskwuff Just by going off the server info from Digital Ocean, it is x32.